# How to use linux command to extract sequencing data

Tags: linux, bioinformatics

I would like to extract certain lines and its following sequencing data.

There is a `ecoli.ffn` file as follows:

```
$head ecoli.ffn
>ecoli16:g027092:GCF_000460315:gi|545267691|ref|NZ_KE701669.1|:551259-572036
ATGAGCCTGATTATTGATGTTATTTCGCGT
AAAACATCCGTCAAACAAACGCTGATTAAT
>ecoli16:g000011:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT
>ecoli16:g000012:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT
CTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
CTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
```

and a index.txt as following

```
$head index.txt
g000011
g000012
```

what I want to do is "extract index.txt from ecoli.ffn", the ideal output is:

```
>ecoli16:g000011:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT
>ecoli16:g000012:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT
CTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
CTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a simple script ecoli.sh using awk:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`cat index.txt`
for i in $a
do
    cat ecoli.ffn|awk -F: -v i="$i" 'BEGIN{flag=0} {if($2 == i){print $0;flag=1;} if(flag ==1 && $2 != i){print $0; flag=0;} }'
done
```

then you need to run this script in your shell.

Comment: Thanks, guodongxiaren. But only the first line of seqencing data is extracted in your way. Actually, the real ecoli.ffn is actually like this: `>ecoli16:g027092:GCF_000460315:gi|545267691|ref|NZ_KE701669.1|:551259-572036
ATGAGCCTGATTATTGATGTTATTT

CGCGTAAAACATCCGTCAAACAAAC

GCTGATTAATGGATTCAACCGGATT
>ecoli16:g000011:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTG

CCGATCTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACT

GGATTCAACCGGATTCAACCGGATT
>ecoli16:g000012:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTG

CCGATCTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACT

`

Comment: some suggestions:  `BEGIN{flag=0}` is useless and can be removed.   `{if($2 == i){print $0;flag=1;}` can be rewritten as `$2==i{print; flag=1}` similarly for the next block.  Regardless, I don't think this is the right answer for the question.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F: -v RS=">" 'NR==FNR{n=split($0,t,"\n");
                             for(i=1;i<n;i++) a[t[i]]; 
                             next} 
                     $2 in a{printf "%s", RS $0}' index file  

>ecoli16:g000011:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGATCTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
>ecoli16:g000012:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGATCTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
```

**UPDATE**
Note that this doesn't depend on how many lines are there for each record.  For the updated input file, same script will give you this output

```
$ awk -F: -v RS=">" 'NR==FNR{n=split($0,t,"\n");
                             for(i=1;i<n;i++) a[t[i]];
                             next}
                     $2 in a{printf "%s", RS $0}' index file

>ecoli16:g000011:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT
>ecoli16:g000012:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT
CTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
CTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
```

Comment: Thanks, karakfa. It works now. But it can only extract the first line of each gene sequencing. The real case is that there are more than two lines of sequences for each gene. As some gene has one line, others may have three or even more lines. How to rescue in this case? Thanks again.

Comment: It shouldn't matter how many lines are there since `>` is the indicator or records.  If your tests indicated otherwise please post an example for the case not working properly.

Comment: As i just updated the question. in that case, it work out as '>ecoli16:g000011:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT
>ecoli16:g000012:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT'

Comment: excuse me, I am sill struggling how to use your command in my file, as I did not see any parameters to indicate ecoli.ffn and gene_id.txt. Can you show me the whole scripts?

Comment: first argument is the index file, the second is the data file.  You'll invoke as `awk ... gene_id.txt ecoli.ffn` where the ... is the full script written above.  That is replace index and file with your filenames.

Comment: I have an additional question in this topic `[here]` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778770/extract-each-sequencing-data-as-individual-file)

Answer (score 0):

This script can be used to filter a FASTA file by a list or file based on their IDs, which seems to be what you are asking for here:

https://github.com/jorvis/biocode/blob/master/fasta/filter_fasta_by_ids.pl