# extract each sequencing data as individual file

Tags: python, linux, bash, awk, sed

There is a `ecoli.ffn` file with rows indicating the name of sequencing genes:

```
$head ecoli.ffn
>ecoli16:g027092:GCF_000460315:gi|545267691|ref|NZ_KE701669.1|:551259-572036
ATGAGCCTGATTATTGATGTTATTTCGCGT
AAAACATCCGTCAAACAAACGCTGATTAAT
>ecoli16:g000011:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT
>ecoli16:g000012:55989:gi|218693476|ref|NC_011748.1|:1128430-1131042
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT
CTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
CTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
```

As shown above, the gene name is between the 1st and 2nd colon:

```
g027092
g000011
g000012
```

I would like to use `ecoli.ffn` to generate three files: `g027092.txt`, `g000011.txt`,`g000012.txt`, containing each sequencing data.

For example, `g027092.txt` will contains the raw data but **without the header**:

```
$cat g027092.txt
ATGAGCCTGATTATTGATGTTATTTCGCGT
AAAACATCCGTCAAACAAACGCTGATTAAT
```

How to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F: -v RS=">" 'NR==FNR{n=split($0,t,"\n");
                             for(i=1;i<n;i++) a[t[i]];
                             next}
                     $2 in a{file=$2".txt"; 
                             sub(/[^\n]+\n/,""); 
                             print > file}' index file


$ head g*.txt
==> g000011.txt <==
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT


==> g000012.txt <==
GTGTACGCTATGGCGGGTAATTTTGCCGAT
CTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC
CTGACAGCTGTTCTTACACTGGATTCAACC


==> g027092.txt <==
ATGAGCCTGATTATTGATGTTATTTCGCGT
AAAACATCCGTCAAACAAACGCTGATTAAT
```

**Explanation**

> `NR==FNR{n=sp...` block parses the first file and creates a lookup
>   table
>
> `$2 in a{file=$2".txt";` if the current record is in the lookup table,
>   set a file name using the key and txt extension
>
> `sub(/[^\n]+\n/,"")` 
>   delete the header line
>
> `print > file` and print to the specified
>   filename.

Comment: Hi @karakfa, can you explain a bit, please?

Comment: It is done. The awk is so powerful and the regular expressions.